# How do I fix my php code that turned unreadable?

Tags: php

I was programming some php validations and the power went out in my house, i booted my pc back up again and

When I opened the file again it showed this

[image]

And the code had turned to this

[image]

Is there anything I can do to fix this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you try to open in notepad .... ?

Comment: Yeah, it shows up the same, just gibberish, I also tried notepad++

Comment: The file's encoding is either broken, or the file is in some binary. Where did you get this file from, or how did you create it?

Comment: Its an assignment from my school, everything worked just fine, the file was not in binary

Comment: By any chance you put it in a (private) git repo? Then you can just delete your local copy and pull it again from your repo. But it indeed looks like your file has gone corrupt. Is this the only broken file in your project?

Comment: First, make a copy of the file. Editing and saving the file while corrupted will break it further, because your chosen editor app might discard everything it cannot decode. Make a copy, everytime you try and fail.